# Register context menu for android gridview

Tags: android, gridview, contextmenu

I'm trying to register a context menu for my gridview. At the moment nothing happens.
Amazingly I couldn't find the answer here.

My gridview is inside main.xml relativelayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:onClick="cameraButtonOnClick"/>

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/addGalleryButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/add_gallery"
        android:onClick="addGalleryButtonOnClick"/>

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/addDirButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/add_dir"
        android:onClick="addDirButtonOnClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_bar"  
/>
```

The gridview is filled with thmbnail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ninovanhooff.projectv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/thumbview"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"


    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/thumb_selector" 
    android:src="@drawable/sample_0" />

<!-- <TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/label_bg"/>

<com.ninovanhooff.projectv.ThreeStateCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/tricheckbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    app:label=""
    app:shadow="false"
    app:state="0"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"> 
</com.ninovanhooff.projectv.ThreeStateCheckBox>
-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that only the imagebutton is preserved to simplify problem

Contextmenu is registered like this:

```
adapter = new ThumbnailAdapter(this);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(gridView);
```

I suspect it's got something to do with android:focusable or android:clickable. But don't know which to try. I tried focusable = false and clickable = false on both the relativelayout and linearlayout of main.xml, but no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got this to work and my suspicion was right. Other elements where stealing the touch events away from intended gridview element. Make sure to remove clickable objects like buttons and checkboxes from your layout to find the culprit. In my case, I had to remove both ImageButton and ThreeStateCheckbox. Another mistake was that I added onclicklisteners to the ImageButton rather than the direct child of gridview (thumbnail.xml). The recommended approach is to use gridview.setOnItemClickListener(listener)). 
Now, this works, but I still need my image and checkbox back. ImageButton was replaced by an ImageView, and I added android:focusable="false" to the checkbox to prevent it from consuming the click event. And everything works fine.

If you can't figure this stuff out, the hierarchyviewer can be enlightening. Maybe you forgot about some tiny element which could steal your touch events. Good luck!